# default(T) with empty collection instead of null

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to have generic method which returns default value for passed type, but for collection type I'd like to get empty collection instead of null, for example:

```
GetDefault<int[]>(); // returns empty array of int's
GetDefault<int>(); // returns 0
GetDefault<object>(); // returns null
GetDefault<IList<object>>(); // returns empty list of objects
```

The method I started to write is following:

```
public static T GetDefault<T>()
{
   var type = typeof(T);
   if(type.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null))
   {
      //return empty collection
   }
   return default(T);   
}
```

How to complete it ?

**EDIT:**
If anyone would like get default value of some type, based on *type instance* instead of *type identifier*, this construction below can be used, i.e.:

```
typeof(int[]).GetDefault();
```

The implementation is internally based on @280Z28 answer:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static object GetDefault(this Type t)
    {
        var type = typeof(Default<>).MakeGenericType(t);
        var property = type.GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var getaccessor = property.GetGetMethod();
        return getaccessor.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the magic of a static constructor to do this efficiently. To use the default value in code, simply use `Default<T>.Value`. The value will only be evaluated for any given type `T` once for the duration of your application.

```
public static class Default<T>
{
    private static readonly T _value;

    static Default()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsArray)
        {
            if (typeof(T).GetArrayRank() > 1)
                _value = (T)(object)Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T).GetElementType(), new int[typeof(T).GetArrayRank()]);
            else
                _value = (T)(object)Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T).GetElementType(), 0);
            return;
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            // string is IEnumerable<char>, but don't want to treat it like a collection
            _value = default(T);
            return;
        }

        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            // check if an empty array is an instance of T
            if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(object[])))
            {
                _value = (T)(object)new object[0];
                return;
            }

            if (typeof(T).IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
            {
                Type elementType = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()[0];
                if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(elementType.MakeArrayType()))
                {
                    _value = (T)(object)Array.CreateInstance(elementType, 0);
                    return;
                }
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException("No default value is implemented for type " + typeof(T).FullName);
        }

        _value = default(T);
    }

    public static T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to complain about thread safety but then it clicked in my brain why you don't need to worry about it. Can you explain more on what is happening so other people don't make the same mistake I was about to

Comment: The runtime guarantees that a static constructor will be called once (and only once) before any external code references a member of the class. Static constructors are always thread safe, although there are other concerns such as leaving the type unusable if the static constructor throws an exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not returning an empty collection each time.  You're returning the same instance of a collection which, although empty initially, is mutable and may not remain that way.

Comment: @BenVoigt empty arrays are immutable.

Comment: @280Z28: True, but the question requires "returns empty list of objects", not only empty arrays.

Comment: @BenVoigt The returned `T[]` implements `IList<T>`, which is the example "list" given in the question.

Comment: It will fail for non generic arrays, e.g. `Default<int[]>.Value`. Can it be fixed ?

Comment: I was hoping `Activator.CreateInstance` would work for array types, but apparently it doesn't. I updated the code to work for both single- and multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @280Z28 - Great code, thank you. About **Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#** , [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has a great discussion in his book "C# in debth":
[http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)
Fourth version of the implementation might be the most suitable one.

Comment: @Tohid this isn't a singleton.

Answer (score 11):

`IList<object>` is not a collection type, it's an interface.  There are *dozens* of possible classes you could return.

If you pass in an actual collection type, you can do this:

```
public static T GetDefault<T>() where T : new
{
   if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
   {
      return new T();
   }
   return default(T);   
}

GetDefault<List<object>>();
```

To handle *both* empty collections, and `null` values of types without default constructors, you can do it like this:

```
public static T GetDefault<T>()
{
   if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
   {
            if (typeof(T).IsGenericType)
            {
                Type T_template = typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (T_template == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                {
                    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Enumerable).MakeGenericType(typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()));
                }
                if (T_template == typeof(IList<>))
                {
                    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()));
                }
            }

      try {
          return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
      }
      catch (MissingMethodException) {} // no default exists for this type, fall-through to returning null
   }
   return default(T);   
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do new IList<object>(), right? You need an implementation. He could just do return new List<T>() instead which returns a concrete implementation of IList<T>.

Comment: Well, the constraint `where T : new` prevents `IList<object>` from being passed to begin with, which is good because an interface is ambiguous when it comes to determining what class to instantiate.

Comment: +1 for the strong typing of `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)`. I was going to say something about that.

Comment: @BenVoigt However won't this solution prevent you from using this class on classes that don't have a default constructor and is not a IEnumerable. I think this needs to be broken in to two functions, If the compiler is not smart enough to call the correct version (I don't know how to do it) you would need the first to call the second and throw a `NotSupportedException` if the IEnumerable does not implement a default constructor.

Comment: @Scott: Yes, if that's a concern one can get rid of the constraint and use `Activator` to try to get an instance from a zero-arg constructor.  (If `Activator` fails then return `null`)

Comment: It will fail for non generic arrays like `int[]`, can it be fixed ?

Comment: @Jaroslaw: For arrays, 280Z28 has provided a good solution, see his code block dealing with `if (typeof(T).AsArray)`

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko: Also, thanks for fixing those errors.  Your fixes look good.  (My answer is definitely "do it like this", not "use this exact code")

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 9, you can ommit type name with constructor. Maybe this is useful in your case.

> ```
> int[] array = new();
> ```

> ```
> var list = MyList?.Select(o => o.Id).ToList() ?? new ();
> ```