# c# get an empty list out of a generic function instead of null

Tags: c#, list, function, generics, return-type

I have a generic function where the T could be anything from int to Dictionary string,string  or List int
if i use 
T tmpOb = default(T);
and return tmpOb later for  int returns 0 which is fine
but for a List int it returns null but it would be realy cool if i could get a empty List int instead.

i could do something like

```
public static T ConvertAndValidate<T>(string bla)
{
    T tmpOb = default(T);
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<int>))
    {
        tmpOb = new List<int>();
    }
    else if(typeof(T) == typeof(List<string>))
    {
        tmpOb = new List<string>();
    }

    //Do other generic stuff that could overwrite the value of tmpOb 

    return tmpOb;
}
```

is their any real generic way to achieve that? Something like

```
public static T ConvertAndValidate<T>(string bla)
{
    T tmpOb = default(T);
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<x>))
    {
        tmpOb = new List<x>();
    }

    //Do other generic stuff that could overwrite the value of tmpOb 
    return tmpOb;
}
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705895/defaultt-with-empty-collection-instead-of-null

Comment: What do you do when `T` is not `List<x>`? If that isn't a valid use case, then you might simply convert to `List<T> ConvertAndValidate<T>(...) { List<T> tmpOb = new List<T>(); ... return tmpOb; }`

Comment: for simple numeric types like int just 0 for Lists or Dictionarys a new empty one with 0 entrys.
Strings being "" would be a benefit but is not needed at the moment all the above cases a covered with the constraint solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, with a generic constraint:

```
public static T ConvertAndValidate<T>(string bla)
    where T : new()
{
    T t = new T();
}
```

Comment: Great seams to be exactly what i need works even for dictonays not only lists!

Comment: @user3289727 Yes, for classes (reference types) the constraint `where T : new()` works whenever the class (which must not be `abstract`) has a `public` instance constructor with zero parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely with your requirement...
But the possible solution to assign a empty list or empty object or for that matter any value type, the below line can be used

```
Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

I hope this should serve your purpose.

Comment: And Above solution works for all possible T types, instead of restricting to reference types.

Comment: thanks for your help your solution is works as good as public static T ConvertAndValidate<T>(string bla)
    where T : new()
with the difference that a string as T throws a exception and in the contraint solution its prevented at compiletime
maybe if i need to use strings i use this way catch the exception and check for typeof(T) == typeof(string) but at the moment i dont need it and prefer a error at compiletime if the T is not compatible

Answer (score 0):

I am also not certain about your needs, but you could change your method to:

```
    private static T ConvertAndValidate<T>(string bla)
    {
        T ret = default(T);
        if (typeof(System.Collections.IList).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            if (typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
            {
                ret = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

This will check if it is an IList and if it contains generic arguments. Thats it...